# Characterization of cosine of rational multiples of $\pi$

Tags: trigonometry, algebraic-number-theory

Given an algebraic number $x$ such that $-1 \leq x \leq 1$ is there a characterization to figure out whether $\cos^{-1}(x)$ is a rational multiple of $\pi$ or not?

One characterization would be that $\exists n :  \cos(n \times \cos^{-1}(x)) = x$

I wanted to know whether there exists a more concrete way of determining this? Or is this undecidable?

Comment: How about $\exists n:(x+i\sqrt{1-x^2})^n=1$?

Comment: That is just another way of saying that it will reach $0$ radians which is saying it will reach itself again.

Comment: We already know that the only rational $x$ are $0,\pm\frac12,\pm1$. I think there's a theorem about there being only finitely $x$ with $x=\sqrt q,q\in\Bbb Q$, also.

Answer (score 0):

Only a tautologous criterion. You are asking whether $x$ is the real part of a root of unity, in other words whether $x$ is of the form $\frac12(\zeta+1/\zeta)$ for a root of unity $\zeta$. Not very useful, I think.